# Data on axis is not in expected order

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data on a graph, but when I do if I use `data_list`, it's all wonky.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

data_list = [('January', 1645480), ('February', 1608476), ('March', 1557113), ('April', 1391652), ('May', 1090298), ('July', 1150535), ('August', 1125931), ('September', 1158741), ('October', 1305849), ('November', 1407438), ('December', 1501733)]
working_list = [('April', 1391652), ('August', 1125931), ('December', 1501733), ('February', 1608476), ('January', 1645480), ('July', 1150535), ('March', 1557113), ('May', 1090298), ('November', 1407438), ('October', 1305849), ('September', 1158741)]

#### GRAPHING
def create_graph(data):
    x, y = zip(*data)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    axes = plt.gca() # Get the Current Axes
    axes.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)  # Turn off scientific 
    # Show data on Y axis points
    for i, j in zip(x,y):
        plt.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j))
    plt.show()

def main():
## Graphing
    create_graph(working_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

But if I use `working_list`, it's correct! (It's in the order of the list. I'm simply trying to get the data to show from Jan - December on X-axis)

[image]

I've been staring at this for too long -- the data looks to be the exact same in each list, only `data_list` has "January" first, through December...I'm not sure why that would throw off the graph like it does.  I did notice that the X-Axis months and the data on the Y axis are correct -- but the line connector is all off, as is the order I expected...

Comment: "January" and "April" are just strings like "Cat" and "Dog". You need to use proper `datetime` objects and set the x-axis formatter accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib currently (as of version 2.1) has a problem with the order of categories on the axes. It will always sort the categories prior to plotting and you have no chance of changing that order. This will hopefully be fixed for the next release, but until then you would need to stick to plotting numeric values on the axes.

In this case this would mean you plot the data against some index and later set the ticklabes accordingly. Of course you could also use DateTimes, but that seems a bit overkill is you already have a list of the months available.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data_list = [('January', 1645480), ('February', 1608476), ('March', 1557113), 
             ('April', 1391652), ('May', 1090298), ('July', 1150535), 
             ('August', 1125931), ('September', 1158741), ('October', 1305849), 
             ('November', 1407438), ('December', 1501733)]

#### GRAPHING
def create_graph(data):
    months, y = zip(*data)
    plt.plot(range(len(months)),y)
    axes = plt.gca() # Get the Current Axes
    axes.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)  
    axes.set_xticks(range(len(months)))
    axes.set_xticklabels(months, rotation=45, ha="right")
    # Show data on Y axis points
    for i, j in enumerate(y):
        plt.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j))
    plt.show()


create_graph(data_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty simple to tweak and makes sense (...well, the idea behind it does, I don't know why Matplotlib sorts my data around).

Comment: As said the reason it sorts the data is that it is assumed categorical. The underlying logic is that it uses `numpy.unique` to find the unique categories (in your case they are already unique, but how would matplotlib know) and `numpy.unique` returns a sorted version of the input. Hence months starting with the letter A come first. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9312) and will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: It's a minor detail, but worth mentioning that using proper dates and date locators on the x-axis will space the ticks proportional to the number of days in each month.

Comment: @PaulH Sure, but in a plot like this, which has one datapoint per month, I acutally would find march being closer to februay than to april rather disturbing and it might look like a design flaw. Especially as having one such value per month probably rather signifies some mean or accumulated value, such that it should not be interpreted as the value for the first of that month (maybe rather the middle or the end, or just "the month's value").

Comment: sure, like i said, "minor"

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib draws lines from point to point in the order that you provide them.

Ticks on the Axes are sorted according to the type of x-values passed (e.g., numerical for quantities, alphabetical for caetgories, chronologically for dates).

If you want to plot these values as dates, you need to pass actual dates to the `plot` method.

So reading between the lines and assuming you want your x-axis to go from January to December and the lines drawn accordingly, here's how I'd do it:

```
from datetime import datetime

from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import dates

raw_list = [('April', 1391652), ('August', 1125931), ('December', 1501733), ('February', 1608476), ('January', 1645480), ('July', 1150535), ('March', 1557113), ('May', 1090298), ('November', 1407438), ('October', 1305849), ('September', 1158741)]
sorted_list = sorted(working_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], '%B'))

def create_graph(data):
    fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
    _x, y = zip(*data)
    x = [datetime.strptime(month, '%B') for month in _x]
    ax.plot(x, y)

    ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)  # Turn off scientific
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%B'))

    for tick in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        tick.set_rotation(45)
        tick.set_rotation_mode('anchor')
        tick.set_horizontalalignment('right')

    for i, j in zip(x,y):
        ax.annotate(str(j), xy=(i, j))
    return fig
```

So `create_graph(raw_list)` does this:

[image]

And So `create_graph(sorted_list)` does this:

[image]